# Проверить является ли введенный в Edit текст числом

Tags: c++, embarcadero

Как проверить является ли введенный в `Edit` текст числом, а не буквой? Есть ли стандартные функции проверки на ошибку?

Comment: 0-9

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы пользователю сразу выскакивало окно об ошибке (ShowMessage), чтобы наличие ошибки определялось до выполнения вычисления, иначе выскочит ошибка программы, что призведет к ее закрытию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перед вычислением берете строку из Edit'а и пробегает по ней циклом проверяя каждый символ на число функцией isDigit(s), где s текущий символ вашей строки, если isDigit возратит false, то вы нашли  ошибку, и выкидываете пользователю сообщение, не делая никаких вычислений.

Либо проверяете строку [регулярным выражением](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

```
^\d+$
```

, и если регулярка ничего не нашла, то введенное значение не число. Для чисел с плавающей точкой подойдет это выражение

```
^\d+\.{0,1}\d*$
```